# How do I access the same field in every struct in my workspace?

Tags: matlab

I have directories with several .mat files. I am using the following code to open them.

```
files = dir('*.mat');
for i=1:length(files)
eval(['load ' files(i).name ]);
end
```

I then get all the files as structs in my workspace. They all have the same fields, and I would like to access a field called .data in all of them. I have tried first saving the names of the structs with:

```
waveNames = whos
```

But I have then failed to access the objects using the information stored there.
Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try creating an array of structs. Don't use an `eval`, try something like `s(i)=load(files(i).name)`, then try something like `nums=[s.my_number]`. Depending what's in your .mat files, your `s` variable may be a struct of structs, so you might have to fiddle a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Justin suggested in a comment, the best thing to do is read the MAT-file into a cell array.

Your use of `eval` is not necessary, you can use the functional form of `load`. This is always the case in MATLAB:

```
func arg
```

is the same as

```
func('arg')
```

So you can do:

```
files = dir('*.mat');
vars = cell(size(files));
for ii = 1:numel(files)
   vars{ii} = load(files(ii).name);
end
```

Now, each `vars{ii}` is a struct where the field names are the variables in the file. Use `fieldnames(vars{ii})` to get the list of variables available.

Assuming each file has a variable called `data`, in a loop you can access `vars{ii}.data`. You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to do the same thing with each `data` element.

It might be possible to read the files into a struct array instead of a cell array, but you need each file to contain exactly the same set of variables, otherwise the assignment won't work:

```
files = dir('*.mat');
vars = struct();
vars(size(files)).data = []; % pre-allocate the vars array
for ii = 1:numel(files)
   vars(ii) = load(files(ii).name);
end
```

Now you have `vars(ii).data`, which is slightly easier to manage than in the cell array. For example you can retrieve all `data` elements using `cat(3,vars.data)` if they are all matrices of the same type and size.

---

However, if all you want to do is read the `data` element from each file, this would be more convenient:

```
files = dir('*.mat');
data = cell(size(files));
for ii = 1:numel(files)
   vars = load(files(ii).name,'data');
   s{ii} = vars.data;
end
```

Now each `s{ii}` is the `data` variable from file number `ii`.

---

According to the comment below, if I understand correctly, each file `AD0_1.mat` contains a struct `AD0_1`, which contains a field `data`. This could be read as follows:

```
files = dir('*.mat');
data = cell(size(files));
for ii = 1:numel(files)
   vars = load(files(ii).name,files(ii).name);
   s{ii} = vars.(files(ii).name).data;
end
```

Comment: ok, so right now I am able to obtain a cell array that contains a struct in each cell. The problem is that I can't do vars{ii,1}.data, because inside each vars{ii,1}, the field name is the name of my file. The files I am trying to open are names AD0_1, AD0_2, etc.... So in order to access the data I want, I would have to type invars(1,1).AD0_1.data

Comment: sorry, `vars(1,1).AD0_1.data` . And again, I would need to do this for every file I have. I am trying to do this in a loop by somehow using the names of the files and typing `data{i} = vars{ii,1}.fieldnames(vars{ii}).data;` but it won't like that cause there is no field actually named "fieldnames(vars{ii})". What should I do?

Comment: @MelBasnak: So each file contains a struct with the name of the file, and data inside it? That doesn't seem like a "nice" way to save data...

Comment: @MelBasnak: Does the update at the bottom of the answer work for you?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, but I couldn't have done it without the help from before, thank you! @Cris Luengo